# cannot select iOS 14.0 on widget extension deployment target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to set the minimum deployment target for my app's widget extension to 14.0, but that option is not available in the project settings.

Is there a reason it isn't supported? This seems to be the case for all extensions, not just widgets.

[image: ios deployment target options]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Choose Target
2. Select Build Setting
3. search "iOS Deployment Target"
4. select other
   [image]
5. enter "14.0"
   [image]

Comment: do you know why it's not enabled in the drop-down?

Comment: I think this is a bug? in xcode, you can see that the version provided to you always skips a version